# Need my Object Code to return a string and convert object into a string

Tags: javascript, object, composite

My code works and outputs "This is Bob Martin from USA."

However, I want my code to: 1.) Have function printBio(user) return a string. The return value from the function should be a string. And 2.) Should convert object into a string with the structure: "This is NAME SURNAME from COUNTRY." function should convert the user object into a properly formatted string and then return that string

```
function printBio (user) {
  
  user = { 
  name: 'Bob',
  surname: 'Martin',
  age: 25,
  address: {
    country: "USA"
  }
}

console.log(`This is ${user.name} ${user.surname} from ${user.address.country}.`);
  return user;
  
}
printBio();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem as you already did make a template, but this is your code rearanged.

```js
const user = {
  name: 'Bob',
  surname: 'Martin',
  age: 25,
  address: {
    country: "USA"
  }
}

function printBio(user) {

  return `This is ${user.name} ${user.surname} from ${user.address.country}.`
}

const bio = printBio(user);

console.log(bio)
```

Comment: You actually solved it for me. It was the last 2 lines, Thanks.